# Grouping all consecutive numbers with their difference

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

How to group all differences between consecutive numbers from associative array? Below is the array which I'm using

**need to group (2,3)(7,8) with they difference , ignore (11,6,5,9)**

```
$array = array(
    2 =>"12",
    3 =>"12",
    11 => "16",
    6 => "15",
    5 => "14",
    7 => "16",
    8 => "17",
    9 => "18")
```

Below is the code which I'm using to group the array, but it's not working:

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    echo  $prev;
    if (isset($prev)) {
        if (($v - $prev) != 1) $newArray[] = $v;
    } else { $newArray[] = $v; }
    $prev = $v;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArray);
```

Currently I'm getting this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 16
    [3] => 15   
    [4] => 16
)
```

**but I need the O/P to be** `(2,3)=0` difference, `(7,8)=1` difference,  i. e.

```
array(
    [0]=>0,
    [1]=>1
);
```

Comment: What is the relationship between (2,3) (7,8) ? Why these keys and ignore the other ones?

Comment: @Touki : only 2 consecutive index need to consider, i.e 1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10, (1,2)(5,6)(9,10)

Comment: The last two indices are also consecutive. Why ignore them?

Comment: @nalply : yes but i have only consider only first two , if two and third consecutive i have ignore them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here you go.

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if (isset($prev) && $k == $prev + 1) {
        $newArray[] = $v - $array[$prev];
    }
    $prev = $k;
}
```

This produces the array for three consecutive pairs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
)
```

If you want to stop after two pairs, add a running counter `$i = 0;` before the `foreach` and exit with `if (++$i >= 2) break;` inside the `if` in the loop:

```
$newArray = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if (isset($prev) && $k == $prev + 1) {
        $newArray[] = $v - $array[$prev];
        if (++$i >= 2) break;
    }
    $prev = $k;
}
```

Comment: is it correct $newArray = array();$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if (isset($prev) && $k == $prev + 1) {
        $newArray[] = $v - $array[$prev]; if ($i++ >= 2){ break;}
    }
    $prev = $k;
}

Comment: : $newArray = array();
 $i = 0;
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if (isset($prev) && $k == $prev + 1) {
        $newArray[] = $v - $array[$prev];
    if ($i++ >= 2) break;
 }
    $prev = $k;
}
print_r($newArray); its gives same results Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
)

Comment: I've made a small mistake (the so-called fence-post error). Use `++$i` instead of `$i++`.